# Getting module error while importing numpy inside package folder

Tags: python, import, lib

#### Case:

In project I have package (pack) and those init file.

Also in main project dir have 2 .py files (f1 and f2).

In pack I have f3.py file (inside importing, for example, numpy lib)

#### Faced with next problem:

When I import to f2 pack.f3 all right, but in importing tis sequence to f1 have error "module numpy not found"

#### Main_dir:

- f1.py
- f2.py
- pack

  - f3.py

Hope for your help. Thanks

Idk cause importing mechanism, which i used in f1 and is equal

Comment: Hi Amali Yarmukhametov, are you sure that numpy is correctly installed on your python envirorment.

Comment: Yes.
Problem solved. thx.
I deleted py file, where I imported dependencies, created new file, pasted all dependencies without editing, and file was launched successful

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. thx. I deleted py file, where I imported dependencies, created new file, pasted all dependencies without editing, and file was launched successful.

Comment: Hi @Amali, great you found a solution. To make it easier for others to follow this post, you could adhere to the naming introduced in the question, e.g, "I deleted f1.py" instead of "I deleted py file, where I imported dependencies".